# Build commands display in sort order in c9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have developed a couple of builders(using New Build System) in c9 online ide.

`In Run Menu -> Build System`.

How can I display Build system commands in sorted order alphabetically or positioned by index??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to reorder build items in Cloud9 at the moment.